# Intellij not recognizing fail cases as a successful test

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, server, backend

I am currently working on a project where I have created some tests to test some failure responses from the server (e.g.: error 501, error 500, error 414...) but when I run those tests, the console gives me the exactly error I was expecting, but Intellij does not treat them as a success. Has somebody already experienced this?

```java
    @Test
    void parseHttpRequestBadMethod1 () {
        try {
            HttpRequest request = httpParser.parseHttpRequest(generateBadTestCaseMethodName());
            fail();
        } catch  (HttpParsingException e) {
            assertEquals(e.getErrorCode(), HttpStatusCode.SERVER_ERROR_501_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
        }
    }
```

```
16:53:34.351 [main] DEBUG com.gui.httpserver.http.HttpParser - Request Line METHOD to Process : GeT

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.gui.httpserver.http.HttpParsingException: Not Implemented

    at com.gui.httpserver.http.HttpParser.parseHttpRequest(HttpParser.java:31)
    at com.gui.httpserver.http.HttpParserTest.parseHttpRequestBadMethod1(HttpParserTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Caused by: com.gui.httpserver.http.HttpParsingException: Not Implemented
    at com.gui.httpserver.http.HttpRequest.setMethod(HttpRequest.java:26)
    at com.gui.httpserver.http.HttpParser.parseRequestLine(HttpParser.java:63)
    at com.gui.httpserver.http.HttpParser.parseHttpRequest(HttpParser.java:29)
    ... 4 more
```

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/Lageh/Server_Java/tree/main) for the project I am currently working on. It is a very simple server using java core.

I tried to wrap with some try/catch to try to catch the error and treat them as a successful test (once my main objective is to validate if the errors responses from the server are working) but it did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your code fails, but I think a more idiomatic approach is to use the "We expect an exception here" facility of the Test framework itself. If you are using JUnit, you can find an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception).